# What is the most efficient way to create a web video chat?

Tags: flash, erlang, video-streaming, chat, real-time

What is the more efficient way to create a web video chat ?

What tecnologies ?

What server side and client side languages ?

What type fo server ?

etc

.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *most* efficient way is to use an existing service. You just add an IFRAME or a JavaScript to your webpage, and that's it!
Otherwise, the tech answer depends on what features you need.

Answer (score 1):

my preferral combo for this setup is : fms + as3 + flex4 compiler

Answer (score 1):

Look at OneTeam Media Server. I haven't tried it myself, but I've seen some impressive demos. It's an Open source flash server written in Erlang, and you can create a Web video chat using it.

http://www.process-one.net/en/blogs/article/oneteam_media_server_by_processone